# javascript Number('.1') is not equal to python Decimal('.1')

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I am sending an js object to Django backend:

```json
  {
    name: "somename", 
    mynumber:Number('.1')
  }
```

In Django backend i have an array:

```py
  arr = [Decimal(".1"),Decimal("1"),Decimal('2'),.....]
```

When i get an integer type number from mynumber front end, python recognizes the number. But when i send an float type number such as **Number('.1')** or **Number('.2')**, this number i cannot compare with python **Decimal('.1')** or **Decimal('.2')**.

How can i send the front end number so that i can compare the number with **Decimal('.1')** or **Decimal('.2')**?

Comment: Did you try just sending as a string and converting to Decimal on the python side?

Comment: yes i did. it works. but i dont want to change backend code. i was wondering if there is a way to send data such that i dont have to change the backend.

Comment: did you try `{ ... , mynumber: .1,  ...}` ?

Comment: yes i did. it does not work. i guess python Decimal() works differently than Number(). i also tried  parseFloat(".1") from js. same result. it does not recognized by pythonas .1

Comment: BTW, pay attention to the fact that .1 is a decimal number (i.e., in radix 10), but **not** the exact value of a float (i.e., a floating-point number in radix 2), so in JavaScript you'll get, for example, `.1 + .1 + .1 === .3` → `false`, because of the error for rounding `".1"` (while in Python, `Decimal(".1") + Decimal(".1") + Decimal(".1") == Decimal(".3")` → `True`)

Comment: So @getup8's suggestion to keep your decimal literals as "strings" as long as possible (before parsing them as proper `Decimal` numbers) certainly seems the way to go in your use case…

Comment: Note however that there are dedicated Decimal libraries for JavaScript that you might want to use: see e.g. this SO answer [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251971/9164010).

Comment: @Aurora  in order to understand better, why on the Back-end, are you using Decimal(str) and not just a float? any particular reason?

Comment: after doing some research i decided that i will make change in the backend file as Decimal(object.mynumber) rather changing in the frontend for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing some investigation on my project i decided that i will change in the backend file as Decimal(object.mynumber) rather changing in the frontend. In this case i have to make changes  in multiple places. But as i think it is better to send backend data as string.